# SQL Server - Need to obtain duplicate records based on mutiple criteria of the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I work with a huge dataset of hospital activity records. Each record represents something done on behalf of a patient. My focus is on patients that have experienced 'outpatient' activity, such as attended an appointment or clinic.
In the data, we get records that are duplicates in that; a patient is shown to have attended their first out patient appointment more than once in a six month period. This is an error on the part of the hospital who send their data. We have to identify these records to send back as challenges.

I have the following SQL statement which is finding records where the 'Patient Code' appears more than once.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Z_ForQueries a
JOIN (SELECT PatientCode
FROM dbo.Z_ForQueries
GROUP BY PatientCode
HAVING COUNT (*) > 1 ) b
ON a.PatientCode = b.PatientCode
WHERE [Multiple OPFA in month] = 'y'
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to syntax the next bit; For each set of duplicated patient codes, I only want to see the records where one of the records has a 'Month' of 7 (that's the just the current month I'm working on). If non of the groups of duplicated records have '7' in the month, then I don't need to see them.

For example, patient code L000066715 has 4 records, I can see that each record represents the same initial outpatient appointment in the same hospital speciality. Obviously you can only 'first attend' once. Each record has a month number; 3,4,6 & 7. Because this patient code has one of their duplicate records in month 7, I need it to be returned in the results along with the other 3 records.

Other patient codes exist in duplicate but none of their records are from month 7, so they don't need to be returned.

I hope I've set the scene properly for some help! Thanks.

Comment: is this TSQL? PL/SQL? MySQl?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    dbo.Z_ForQueries a
JOIN (
    SELECT   PatientCode,
             MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateColumn) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As InMonth
    FROM     dbo.Z_ForQueries
    GROUP BY PatientCode
    HAVING   COUNT (*) > 1 
     ) b    ON  a.PatientCode = b.PatientCode
            And InMonth = 1
WHERE [Multiple OPFA in month] = 'y'
```

Explanation:

The CASE expression returns 1 for rows where Month=7, and 0 in all other cases.  The MAX(..) around this CASE expressions thus returns 1 if *any* rows in the GROUP had a Month=7 and a 0 only if *none* of them did.

Comment: Whoops, missed the timelimit, meant to say; Thanks @RBarryYoung. It's gotten me a bit closer. I tweaked the MAX statement as I forgot to mention, my month column isn't a datetime, it contains integers that represent months. The amount of results have about halved, but it's still giving me records where the duplicated patient code has no month '7' on one of the duplicates. I'm punching above my weight here with this, as I don't fully understand what the MAX statement is doing with the sub CASE statement. Learning curve!!

Comment: @steveck79 Explanation appended to my answer.

Comment: Ah, my understanding is expanded! Thanks. I've taken out the WHERE clause, because what you've very helpfully done is put me on a path to not needing to use a whole chunk of previous processing that got the column with the 'y's involved to begin with. It's great to hopefully not need it. I'm trying to figure out now why the query is allocating a '1' to [patientcode] records that don't have a month '7'. Wood for trees and all that!